# Angular 6 - Method always returning -1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service and I'm trying to update a record and this just injust the changes into the component's data.

**listData** holds all the data.

The variables all contain data.

**Example: 1, 1, my title, post text**

**result** is returning successfully into the service. But after I

```
update(id, userId, title, body) {
    this.apiService.updateById(id, userId, title, body).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);

        // PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        const currentItemIndex = this.listData.findIndex((item: {id: number}) => item.id === id);

        console.log(`CurrentIndex is: ${currentItemIndex}`); // Returns -1

        // THIS IS NEVER REACHED
        if (currentItemIndex > -1) {
            this.listData.splice(currentItemIndex, 0, {userId: userId, title: title, body: body});
        }

      },
      error => {
      console.log('There was an error: ', error); // No errors returned
    }
  );

}
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: What is content listData

Comment: That variable is holding this data: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the findIndex as:

```
this.listData.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
```

I don't think showing the type of `item` is a correct argument for `findIndex`

```js
let listData = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }]
  
  // say id was 2
  
  let id = 2;
  
  let foundIndex = listData.findIndex((eachData) => {
    // === when its and integer, is it in your case?? 
    // if not then try with ==
    return eachData.id === id;
  });
  
  console.log(foundIndex)
```

Comment: Still giving me -1

Comment: @MarkHill2018: Okay, can you `console.log(id)` before you findIndex?

Comment: OK, the id is correct. If I try to edit record with ID 2 ... id will return 2

Comment: @MarkHill2018: Is it a string or an integer? try with `==` rather than `===`?